# How can I "Install" a self-contained, zipped program?

Tags: windows, installation

Typically, most Windows programs come with a `setup.exe` installer. The installer will do a few things:

- Extract the program to a destination folder `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`
- Create a Start Menu shortcut
- Create a Desktop shortcut
- Add a program entry to `Programs and Features` for an easy uninstall

However, there are some self-contained programs which come without installers, typically in the form of a single ZIP file (i.e. [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/)).

I'd like to keep these self-contained programs in `Program Files` as I would any installed program. Currently, my solution for a zipped program is:

1. Determine if the program is 32 or 64 bit.
2. Move the program to `Program Files`.
3. Create a Start Menu shortcut.
4. Create a Desktop shortcut.
5. Remember to undo all this when I want to uninstall.

Is there a way I can automate this? Or is there a better, alternative way to store self-contained programs?

**How can I "install" a self-contained zipped program in Windows?**

Comment: Is [that](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/zipinst.html) what you have in mind?

Comment: Btw, ScreenToGif has an installer since v2.9 :)